# python sort lists from 1 list based on date elements

Tags: python, sorting

I have 3 lists. Currently I am using 1 list to sort all list like this:

```
sorted_lists = sorted(zip(new_date_list, flipkart_sale_list, paytm_sale_list), key=lambda x: x[0])
new_date_list, flipkart_sale_list, paytm_sale_list = [[x[i] for x in sorted_lists] for i in range(3)]
```

The new date list contains date strings as element which are in format of `%b %d`.

```
new_date_list = ['Feb 01', 'Feb 02', 'Jan 04', 'Jan 05', 'Jan 06', 'Jan 07']
flipkart_sale_list = [5000,4000,3000,6000,1000,9000]
paytm_sale_list = [2200,2500,3500,5000,4000,1000]
```

However The above code is not sorting the date string properly. So how to sort the all the lists according to new_date_lists?

The other two lists contains numbers.

Expected Result:

```
new_date_list = ['Jan 04', 'Jan 05', 'Jan 06', 'Jan 07', 'Feb 01', 'Feb 02']
flipkart_sale_list = [3000,6000,1000,9000,5000,4000]
paytm_sale_list = [3500,5000,4000,1000,2200,2500]
```

Comment: Your expected result and your statement "how to sort the all the lists according to new_date_lists" are contradictory. What do you really want? Sort all lists according to `new_date_list` or sort all the list separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to datetime objects before sort. Try

```
sorted_lists = sorted(zip(new_date_list, flipkart_sale_list, paytm_sale_list), key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[0], "%b %d"))
new_date_list, flipkart_sale_list, paytm_sale_list = [[x[i] for x in sorted_lists] for i in range(3)]
```

Result:

```
>>> new_date_list
['Jan 04', 'Jan 05', 'Jan 06', 'Jan 07', 'Feb 01', 'Feb 02']
>>> flipkart_sale_list
[1000, 9000, 5000, 4000, 3000, 6000]
>>> paytm_sale_list
[4000, 1000, 2200, 2500, 3500, 5000]
```

As suggested by @StefanPochmann, this

```
new_date_list, flipkart_sale_list, paytm_sale_list = [[x[i] for x in sorted_lists] for i in range(3)]
```

can also be done by zip

```
new_date_list, flipkart_sale_list, paytm_sale_list = map(list, zip(*sorted_lists))
```

Comment: Why not use `zip` for the second part as well?

Comment: @StefanPochmann yes I did that first then I changed the result to match OP's code.

Comment: You don't need `map` here the "star expression" works with iterable. 
`new_date_list, flipkart_sale_list, paytm_sale_list = zip(*sorted(zip(new_date_list, flipkart_sale_list, paytm_sale_list), key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], "%b %d")))`

Comment: @user3100115 Yes, It does! But it returns list of tuples. There were lists in OP's expected result so I added `map(list` to convert tuples to lists.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir Yes but frankly I  think converting the sorted result  to a list doesn't make any sense. It will be better to post the sorted tuple as result then tell OP that he can convert the `tuple` to `list` if necessary using `map`. Also you don't need the `sorted_lists` variable. Last but not least: remove the *try* in the first line to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did not really get the 3 lists purpose but  if u got one big list do
this trick.

```
import datetime

sorted(new_date_list, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%b %d'))
```

**edit - after u've added the lists data example - i'd do the sort 3 times